# how to localize red regions in heatmap using opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, heatmap

I am generating a heat map using an anomaly detection framework, and the output is something like this image.

the output is like this:

[image]

How can I mark the red regions on the original images? like a circle around the red part on the original image.

Comment: When you generate the heat map, you have a single-channel intensity image. Simply threshold to create a mask with only the desired intensity levels and detect blobs.

Comment: always remember: false-color *illustrations* are *not data*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So let's say you have this heatmap.

[image: Heatmap]

It was actually generated from some intensity data, some `prediction` you obtained from your algorithm. That's what we need, not the heatmap itself. It is usually a "grayscale image", it has no color, only intensity values. Usually it is from 0.0 to 1.0 (could be also from 0 to 255) and if you were to plot it, it would like that.

[image: Prediction]

So now to obtain "red" areas you just need regions with high intensity. We must do "thresholding" to obtain them.

```
max_val = 1.0             # could be 255 in your case, you must check
prediction /= max_val     # normalize
mask = prediction > 0.9
```

Threshold in this case is 0.9, you can make it smaller to make "red" regions larger. We will get the following mask:

[image: Thresholded mask]

Now we can either blend this mask with our original image:

```
alpha = 0.5    
original[mask] = original[mask] * (1 - alpha) + np.array([0, 0, 255]) * alpha
```

... and get this:

[image: Masked image]

Or we can find some contours on the mask and encircle them:

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask.astype(np.uint8), 
                               cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
                               cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for cnt in contours:
    center = np.average(cnt, axis=0)
    radius = np.max(np.linalg.norm((cnt - center)[:, 0], axis=1))
    radius = max(radius, 10.0)
    cv2.circle(original, center[0].astype(np.int32), int(radius), (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

... to get this:

[image: Circled]